# Unable to connect to Network Adapter (Cellular Data)

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-8.1, windows-10

I have a number of **Fujitsu Q702** Tablets that have been very problematic with regards to connecting to a mobile broadband connection (via SIM Card). These used to work fine up until a few weeks ago.

OS: Windows 8.1/10

I've tried:

- Re-installing the drivers through the Fujitsu DeskUpdate application.
- Re-installing the drivers manually.
- Changing SIM cards, including SIM cards from different network providers.
- Going through Services and Adapter IPv4 Settings - all seems well.
- Resetting the OS.
- Resetting the BIOS.
- Updating BIOS Firmware.
- Contacted Fujitsu Support - they told me to re-install the drivers (which I had already done).

I have also installed Sierra AirCard Watcher, it is stating that the adapter is in "Device safety mode".

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Reinstall the OS. (unless it's that you mean by resetting the device)

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: Give up?  Not every problem has a feasible solution, and it sounds like you've taken all the reasonable steps you can to fix this one.

Comment: Use cellular usb dongle ?

Comment: This is not clear: Have _all_ the tablets failed, or only _some_ of them?

Comment: Giving up is not really a solution in my opinion at least. I am trying to avoid   using a USB dongle and 4/14 of these Tablets have failed so far. I'm guessing it was an OS update that caused this.

Comment: The tablets were sent to the supplier where it was determined that it was a hardware issue.